# Amazon SES - Reject mails based on size

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have been trying to configure Amazon SES for receiving emails to my domain, and reject mails which are above a certain size limit.

I am able to get the notification data into a lambda service, where I can see all the common headers but the "Content-Length" header as mentioned in Amazon documentation does not exist in the data I received in the Lambda event.

Is there any configuration I have to do to get those headers? Or is there any other way I can stop accepting mails which is above a certain size?

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring AWS for the moment. When it comes to attachments there are 2 limiting factors, the SMTP configuration and the recipient mail server limitations.

SES has a maximum message size (message including attachments) of 10MB.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/limits.html

Amazon WorkMail (as an example of a recipient mail server) has a maximum message size (message including attachments) of 25MB.
https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/faqs/

These configurations are Amazon defaults. I would recommend raising a support request with AWS if you want the SMS maximum message size to be reduced.

Comment: Currently, Amazon increased their minimum mail receiving size from 10 Mb to 30 Mb for those mails which are stored in S3. I am trying to limit the mails which are going to the S3 bucket based on the size as per the business case. I will try reaching out to AWS support and see what they have to say. Thanks.

Comment: Had you contacted AWS Support? Were you able to reject emails larger than certain KBs?